# Extracting data from a json.loads list

Tags: python

I am trying to extract a specific column or layer, not sure what you want to call it.. that is inside a json object of which I have converted to what I think is a layered list but I have two problems, my check to see if "return" is in the list is not finding anything even though when printing jsonb I can see it is in the list, my second problem is how do I extract a certain column from a layer.. in this case I need the number "43343243" out the second layer and put into a variable I tried referencing it with jsonb["return"][0] and I got a key error..

My code:

```
def worker(pairtxt):    
    while (1 < 2):            
        balanceobject = requests.post(urlauth, headers=headers, data=paybytes)
        json_stringb = str(balanceobject.content, 'utf8')
        jsonb = json.loads(json_stringb)
        print(jsonb)
        if "return" in jsonb: #fails
           print(jsonb["return"]["0"]) # key error
           print(jsonb["return"]) # prints everything even layers under the number
```

My jsonb print output

```
{'success': 1, 'return': {'43343243': {'status': 0, 'pair': 'rgeg',
 'type': 'sell', 'amount': 0.01000002, 'rate': 1.0,
 'timestamp_created': 1502642258}}}
```

Comment: Your `jsonb["return"]` has only one key: '43343243'. It does not have key '0'. That's why you get the key error.

Answer (score 1):

Because 43343243 is a key not a value, you need to get the keys of return :

```
jsonb = {'success': 1, 'return': {'43343243': {'status': 0, 'pair': 'rgeg', 'type': 'sell', 'amount': 0.01000002, 'rate': 1.0, 'timestamp_created': 1502642258}}}
numberWanted = list(jsonb['return'].keys())[0]
print(numberWanted) # => 43343243
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at the output `jsonb` as a list (which is not true). `jsonb` is a dictionary. To verify that you can do this:

```
print(type(jsonb))
```

A dictionary has key-value pairs. 
success is a key and 1 is the value.
return is a key and the value is another dictionary.

```
{
    '43343243': {
                'status': 0, 
                'pair': 'rgeg', 
                'type': 'sell', 
                'amount': 0.01000002, 
                'rate': 1.0, 
                'timestamp_created': 1502642258
            }
}
```

If you want to access `43343243`, then you can do `jsonb['return']['43343243']`